# Gradle - Cannot set property on null object

Tags: gradle, gradle-properties

I have a .gradle in which I want to set some project properties if a condition is true.

```
def isRelease = project.getProperty('isRelease')

if (isRelease) {
    println 'Detected a release'
    project.properties.'releaseCenter'.'uploadURL' = project.properties.'uatUploadURL'
}
```

The output is:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tasks'.
> Cannot set property 'uploadURL' on null object
```

I think it has to do with the '' around the object name but I couldn't get it to work.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `project.properties`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getProperties--

which returns a `Map`. You then call `properties.'releaseCenter'` which is equivalent to doing `properties.get("releaseCenter")` which returns `null`. You try to get a property on a `null` object which is exactly the error you are seeing.

Possible solutions:

1. Fix your Gradle configuration (some plugin may be adding this property)
2. Define the property yourself.